# Enumerations in totally ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Suppose that $A$ is a subset of the *positive* integers and you want to enumerate all the elements of $A$ in a sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ such that $a_n < a_{n+1}$. What is the most concise and unambiguous way to refer to $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$? Would an expression like "Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be the unique increasing enumeration of $A$" be correct?

Comment: Yes, sounds fine.

Comment: Yet, I am hesitant because this phrasing doesn't seem to be corroborated by a search on Google: https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=cr&ei=nEVdUsTXJYGWtQa9woHYCw#q=%22the+unique+increasing+enumeration+of+%22.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, hence so is each subset.

Comment: Yes, so what?!?

Answer (score 1):

As written this need not exist; if $A=\mathbb{Z}$ then there is no strictly increasing enumeration, as the set is unbounded below.  If $A$ is bounded below then the proposed notation is fine.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant positive integers.